# Is the operation inside foreachRDD supposed to be blocking?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In a Spark Streaming job, is the operation inside foreachRDD supposed to synchronous / blocking?

What if you do some asynchronous operation which returns a Future? Are you then supposed to do Await on that Future?

*Note*: This question is specifically about Spark Streaming and foreachRDD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Futures within Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478871/using-futures-within-spark)