# Spark parallellize simple operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As I understand it, you can not create new RDD's or DF's from within a map function. As this would try and serialize the whole spark context to executors.

Let's say I have a few of the following pseudo code in my driver:

```
df1 = sc.readtextfiles(/1.txt)
df2 = sc.readtextfiles(/2.txt)
df3 = sc.readtextfiles(/3.txt)

sc.write(DoSomeOperation(df1))
sc.write(df2.union(df3))
```

is there a way to still do these operations in parallel? Or will the driver have to do this sequentially?

Comment: Spark relies on `RDD` for distribution, so if what you do is not "collection-like", then you will need to use another feature/library for parallelization. In your case, it seems like scheduling two spark jobs would work, as you wouldn't need your spark-drivers to communicate.

Comment: A usecase for instance would be: do an operation based on the name of a file, where order of execution could be an issue.

Comment: but the operations on different files can be done async? Then you can schedule spark jobs from a main Scala program based on the file name...A more experienced Scala developper should answer. I think that the fact that the jobs run on Spark doesn't interfere with the logic.

Comment: @Havnar : Look at this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478871/using-futures-within-spark?rq=1

Comment: I've had a look at future, but I guess it's the closest thing to an improvement over sequentially processing things, be it statically or in a loop.

Comment: Another usecase maybe: "download a file from some source and place it in hdfs" If I want to download 30 files and I have 20 executors.
I would first have to download all of them and then start processing, instead of starting a whole transformation chain on them. Setting up different jobs for this would introduce a lot of overhead. Or am I missing some concept here?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
val fileNames = Array("/1.txt", "/2.txt", "/3.txt").parallelize()
val result = fileNames.map(data -> DoSomeOperation(data))
result.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output.txt")
```

Comment: That depends... the answer would be no.
 Unless you have some `sc.readTextfile(data)` in the `DoSomeOperation` method. Then the answer would be yes.

Comment: @Havnar Of course, my bad. The full operation should be `val result = fileNames.map(names -> sc.readTextFile(names)).map(data -> DoSomeOperation(data))`