# Is it possible to perform asynchronous execution in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have confirmed that the order of operation of spark scala is from top to bottom of source.
However, I like the javascript callback function...
I want to run a specific function at the same time.

Is it possible to perform asynchronous execution in spark scala?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478871/using-futures-within-spark) answer might help

Comment: The question sounds ambiguous. Please, give more details with some example. When you say "from bottom to source", do you mean a block of code inside a mapPartition function?, or in a UDF?. Because in a Spark SQL pipeline trtansformations+actions Spark optimizer takes the control...

Comment: The short answer is "no, it is not possible". A bit longer explanation would involve a realization that you are _wrong_: spark does not _not_ execute "from to bottom of source". You can split the data source into partitions, and process as many as you want in parallel. Parallelism is built into spark, you don't need to do anything extra about it, your code will always run in parallel as it is. If your "specific function" does processing of the source data, you are looking for `map` or `mapPartition` or a spark UDF, if it's just doing some unrelated work, you don't need spark for that.