# How to execute async operations (i.e. returning a Future) from map/filter/etc.?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a `DataSet.map` operation that needs to pull data in from an external REST API.

The REST API client returns a `Future[Int]`.

Is it possible to have the `DataSet.map` operation somehow await this `Future`  asynchronously? Or will I need to block the thread using `Await.result`? Or is this just not the done thing... i.e. should I instead try and load the data held by the API into a `DataSet` of its own, and perform a `join`?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Different from: [Spark job with Async HTTP call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899843/spark-job-with-async-http-call)

Reason: This question is open to discussing how to solve the problem differently, say, using a second `DataSet` and a `join` instead. Furthermore, the linked question contains no definitive answer as to whether Spark can handle asynchronous transformations - and if it can - how they should be structured.

Comment: Just in case if any one looking for spark job with async http call.. [checkout 
 this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946369/150371)

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting question (that I don't think is a duplicate of the other question either).

Yes, you can submit Spark jobs which is to say that the Spark jobs are going to be  executed asynchronously (leaving the main calling thread free to do whatever it wants after the call). This is [SparkContext.submitJob](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@submitJob[T,U,R](rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T],processPartition:Iterator[T]=%3EU,partitions:Seq[Int],resultHandler:(Int,U)=%3EUnit,resultFunc:=%3ER):org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction[R]).

Yes, you can run Spark jobs simultaneously from multiple threads using the very same `SparkContext`, i.e. `SparkContext` is thread-safe.

Given the two options, you can have a thread pool (using [java.util.concurrent.Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)) and execute Spark jobs that in turn execute an asynchronous action, say *"pull data in from an external REST API that returns a Future[Int]."*

Now, this part has nothing to do with Spark. How you want to get notified about the result of a `Future[Int]` is up to you. You can `Await` or just register a callback to get called when a `Success` or a `Failure` happen. It's up to you and have nothing to do with Spark.

What does matter is how you're going to submit or run a Spark job since `map` alone won't do this. `map` is a transformation. I'd rather use `foreachPartition` instead that would do the external call.