# pyspark is hanging while attempting to make URL requests in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have an rdd of URLs and I want to make url requests in parallel. I am running get_menus with an rdd of url strings. Pyspark hangs when trying to collect(), take(), etc. on items.

```
def format_json(response, slug):
    clean_response = str(response)[:-1]
    clean_response += ", 'slug': '" + slug + "'}\n" # ', \"store-slug\": \"' + slug +'\"}'
    clean_response = clean_response.replace("None", "null").replace("True", 'true').replace("False", "false")
    return clean_response

def get_all(url, slug):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response = json.loads(response).get('data', {})
    clean_response = format_json(response, slug)
    return clean_response

def get_items(rdd_of_urls):
    get_items_udf = udf(lambda x: get_all(x), StringType())
    items = rdd_of_urls.map(get_items_udf)
    return items
```

I see many GC allocation errors but don't know how to interpret them:

```
2019-08-21T18:40:04.666+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-08-21T18:40:04.666+0000: [ParNew: 34369K->1837K(36864K), 0.0029907 secs] 127948K->95416K(186848K), 0.0030414 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-08-21T18:40:04.951+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-08-21T18:40:04.951+0000: [ParNew: 34605K->2576K(36864K), 0.0036551 secs] 128184K->96155K(186848K), 0.0037126 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899843/spark-job-with-async-http-call

Comment: instead of map try using mapPartition in spark